# How interact between multiple jQuery Functions and change background image on click with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My first problem is when you click on the black or light gray square box i want to change the background of the square and when you click it again, to revert back to the original image.

The second problem I am having is you will notice when you click on either of the boxes another window slides out. I want to make it, if you click the black box and have the window come out, then press the gray square it sends the window from the black box back and then opens the window from the gray square. I will have a website linked below so you can go check it out if you don't understand what I need. On the website , you will notice when you click the speaker icon on the left sidebar a window slides out and then if you click on the book icon it send the window from the speaker back, then opens the book window! Please Help! I am still a little new to jQuery and am having a bit of trouble with this! I have tried sprites with jQuery which is difficult because I already use the sprite for hover. I have tried toggleClass and some if/else statements. I might just be making the functions wrong but I can not get anything to work!

HTML

```
<div id="sidemenu">
    <div id="regionsContainer">
        <div id="regionsUnitedStates" class="not-open">
        <div id="regionsUnitedStatesTooltip"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="regionsCanada" class="not-open">
         <div id="regionsCanadaTooltip"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="regionsUnitedStatesChooseState"></div>
    <div id="regionsCanadaChooseProvince"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sidemenu {
    width: 60px;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 60px;
    background-color: #383D3F;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    left: -60px;
    transition: left ease-in-out 0.5s;
    top: 0;
}
#sidemenu.show {
    left: 0;
}
#regionsContainer {
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 60px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #383D3F;
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;
}
#regionsUnitedStates {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color:#111111;
}
#regionsUnitedStatesTooltip {
    opacity:0;
    background-color:#000;
    height:60px;
    width:180px;
    left:100px;
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    top:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#regionsUnitedStates.not-open:hover #regionsUnitedStatesTooltip{
    left: 60px;
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    }
#regionsUnitedStates:hover {
    background-position:bottom;
}
#regionsUnitedStatesChooseState{
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    left: -500px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #505759;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
#regionsUnitedStatesChooseState.show {
    left: 60px;
    z-index:-1;
}
#regionsCanada {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color:#666;
}
#regionsCanadaTooltip {
    opacity:0;
    background-color:#000000;
    height:60px;
    width:120px;
    left:100px;
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    top:60px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#regionsCanada.not-open:hover #regionsCanadaTooltip{
    left: 60px;
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    }
#regionsCanada:hover {
    background-position:bottom;
}
#regionsCanadaChooseProvince{
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    left: -500px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #505759;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
#regionsCanadaChooseProvince.show {
    left: 60px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function(slideSidemenu) {
    setTimeout(function() { $("#sidemenu").addClass("show") }, 500);
});
$(function(regionsUnitedStatesChooseState) {
    $("#regionsUnitedStates").on("click", function() {
        $("#regionsUnitedStatesChooseState").toggleClass("show");
        $("#regionsUnitedStates").toggleClass("not-open");
    });
});
$(function(regionsCanadaChooseProvince) {
    $("#regionsCanada").on("click", function() {
        $("#regionsCanadaChooseProvince").toggleClass("show");
        $("#regionsCanada").toggleClass("not-open");
    });
});
```

EXAMPLE WEBSITE: http://intothearctic.gp/en/

EXAMPLE OF MY CODE: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dGbHm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally easier to use classes instead of ID for tasks like this.

Here's an example where I added class `navBtn` to the click elements and `content` to the sliding panels

```
var  $content=$('.content'), 
$navBtn=$('.navBtn').click(function(){
    var $btn=$(this).removeClass('not-open');
    /* get index of current navBtn in relation to collection of all navbtn */
    var btnIndex= $navBtn.index($btn);
    /* remove class from all content then add to the one with index that matches the button*/
    $content.removeClass('show').eq(btnIndex).addClass('show');
    /* add class to other buttons */
    $navBtn.not($btn).addClass('not-open');     

});
```

Although you only currently have 2 sets this is scaleable to unlimited sets without changing anything. It is using indexing so the order of content to buttons needs to match to create same index position for each

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dGbHm/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: How did you make this work? I copied the code to my program and just changed some names around to better relate it to my code to better understand it and nothing slides out at all anymore??

Comment: did you add applicable classes to markup? Are events firing? Are errors thrown? Too many unknowns without you updating demo

Comment: use browser console to look at errors. Will see that you missed consverting a variable `$button is undefined`. Also you are using same variable name for outer collections as well as instance which will cause problems

Comment: Awesome! I fixed that and now it works good! :) except you can not click the button a second time to return it? If you don't mind I would like to ask you one more thing. Can I add jQuery to that so that when one of the buttons is clicked the background image of the button changes and removes the css hover?

Comment: use css class rules for display issues like background